# Browser is not in sync while debugging the protractor with Type Script and VS Code

Tags: protractor

I am new to the protractor and trying to debug the code in VS Code. The browser is launched as expected and not in sync with debugging. After clicking on continue the whole scenario is executed on the browser.

Below is my configuration file.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/built/conf.js"]
    }
]
```

code where am trying to debug:

```
/**
  * Enter userName
  */
 public enterUserName(): Promise<void> {
        try{
            return <Promise<void>> element(by.name(this.userNameLocater)).sendKeys("admin@XXX.com");
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Error while entering the user name " + err);
        }  
    }
    /**
     * Enter password
     */
    public enterPassword(): Promise<void> {
        try{
            return <Promise<void>> element(by.name(this.passwordLocater)).sendKeys("PWD");
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Error while entering the password " + err);
        }  
    }

    /**
     * click on signin button
     */
    public clickSignin(): Promise<void> {
        try{
            return <Promise<void>> element(by.tagName(this.signinbttonLocater)).click();
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Error while clicking on signin button" + err);
        }  
    }

    /**
     * Login success fully 
     */
    public login(): Promise<void> {
        try{
            this.enterUserName();
            this.enterPassword();
            return this.clickSignin();
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Error while signing in" + err);
        }

    }
```

Below is the Spec.ts with just a single scenario.

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
import 'jasmine';
import {LoginCls} from '../Pages/loginCls';

let login = new LoginCls('loginEmail','loginPassword','button');

describe("Login to application", function () {
    it("Should login Successful", function () {
        browser.get("");
        login.login().then(() => {
            var text = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/home-comp/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]'));
            expect(text.getText()).toContain('Welcome,  Administrator Super Admin!');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the full source code of your `*.e2e-spec.ts` file?

Comment: @WillHuang Edited with the spec.ts Thanks.

Comment: you should try to use async/await model to handle Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use `async/await` pattern to handle promise. See below:

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
import 'jasmine';
import {LoginCls} from '../Pages/loginCls';

let login = new LoginCls('loginEmail','loginPassword','button');

describe("Login to application", () => {
    it("Should login Successful", async () => {
        await browser.get("");
        try {
            var text = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/home-comp/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]'));
            expect(await text.getText()).toContain('Welcome,  Administrator Super Admin!');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works now, but should I add async/await only for debugging purpose? Because general execution was as expected without async/await.

Comment: @raj I use `async/await` always. Not just for debugging.